# User specific routing in Istio / Kuberentes

Tags: routes, kubernetes, grpc, istio

I'm wondering if Istio is a good tool to support a particular routing situation, and if not (or even if it is), what other approaches are available.

- I have two microservices, X and Y, with have some number of replicas for each.
- X sends requests to Y.
- X sends requests as a particular user, say "bob".
- Some subset of the replicas of Y (not all!) can handle requests for the user "bob".
- The subset of Y that can handle requests for "bob" is not static but changes over-time depending on some state stored at a replica that is ephemeral.

So when X sends requests, it must determine for the user it is sending the request ("bob"), which subset of Y can that particular request be sent to?

In Istio, there are examples of a routing rule that is associated with a user by looking at the HTTP headers. For the sever side, Y, would I simply have code in Y that calls the **k8s** API to add and remove labels against the replicas Pod?

e.g.,

```
Service-Y.Pod-1.Labels = {
  "user-bob": "true",
  "user-jane": "true",
  ...
}
```

Unclear how well labels handle this, or if this kind of routing should be lifted up to the application layer rather than trying to encode it in a largely transparent service mesh layer.

Answer (score 0):

You have the [open API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.10/#-strong-api-overview-strong-) from K8s. You can make some code which will add a label to pods and then route this traffic to your pods.